# Can I trust user input in wp_redirect()?

Tags: wp-redirect

I'm doing a small plugin that is doing this:

```
$Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
wp_redirect( 'http://old.example.com'.$Path );
exit;
```

I think that's safe, even if there's user input (request uri) in the function, anyway it should be equivalent to directly typing old.example.com/malicious_url, right?

Comment: not sure what is the question here. If it is "can I trust user input" he answer is always "no". but if it is "Can I feed any garbage to `wp_redirect` without bringing the end of life as we know it" the answer is most probably yes. As for the other part... there is nothing that prevent that `REQUEST_URI` to be different than what the user actually "typed", so it depends on the exact setting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can never trust user input. Always prepare a value that you want use in your own code. Example:

```
$path = filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL );

if ( $path )
{
    $url         = 'http://old.example.com' . $path;
    $url_escaped = esc_url( $url );
    $status      = 301;
    $message     = "Moved to <a href='$url_escaped'>$url_escaped</a>.";

    wp_redirect( 'http://old.example.com'. $path, $status );
    wp_die( $message, 'Moved', $status );
}
```